# Converting VB.NET code into a Stored procedure

Tags: sql, .net

I would like to convert the code below into a stored procedure. I cannot really work out how to do it.  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
If NextApproverType = "" Or NextApproverType = "V" Then
        DBF.ExecuteNonQuery("Update JobOrders set Jo_Status='5' where  jo_number='" & ViewState("Jonumber") & "'", , CommandType.Text)

End If

If Trim(ApproverType) = "JA" Then
    If txtApproverComments.Text <> "" Then
        DBF.ExecuteNonQuery("Update JONotes set AApproverNotes=IsNull(AApproverNotes,' ')+'" & vbCrLf & txtApproverComments.Text & vbCrLf & "--" & DBF.ExecuteScalar("select lastname +', '+ firstname +' '+ isnull(middlename,'') from menu_user where userid='" & Session("userid") & "'", , CommandType.Text) & "',ANoteEnterOn='" & Now.Date() & "' where Jo_number='" & ViewState("Jonumber") & "'", , CommandType.Text)
    End If
```

Comment: Use parameters in your query and put that in a stored procedure. Then use the variables in your .NET code as parameters and call the stored procedure.

Comment: people are going to ask what have you tried. Its difficult to get the work done by the members here. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a stored procedure like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE My_Procedure
@ApproverType NVARCHAR(10) ,
@txtApproverComments NVARCHAR(50) = NULL ,
@jo_number NVARCHAR(50)
AS 
    IF @ApproverType = 'ja' 
        BEGIN
            IF @txtApproverComments IS NULL 
                BEGIN UPDATE  JobOrders SET Jo_Status = '5' WHERE jo_number = @jo_number         
                END
        END
```